# Function to get input and assigns it to variable

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I'm trying to make something using javascript/jquery that is similar to java.

The way to get input in java:

```
String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a value: ");
```

.showInputDialog shows GUI and submits a value after "Submit" is clicked.

This is what I've tried: https://jsfiddle.net/1t5pxhj5/2/

Comment: @Satpal yes prompt is kind of what I need, but I'm trying to make my own GUI.

Comment: I think I fixed you the code ?
https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/1t5pxhj5/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is not possible with Javascript.

You should use events and callbacks to retrieve the specified value.

Your Java code:

```
String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a value :");
```

Your Javascript code:

```
function showInput(message, callback) {
    // display dialog
    // ...

    callback($("input").val()); // this should be returned to getInput after Submit is clicked
});

showInput("Enter a  value:", function(x) {
    // do something now 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txt"/>
<input type="button" onclick="gettext('txt');"/>
```

to retrieve data use code below

```
function gettext(id) {
    var entereddata = document.getElementById(id);
    var value = entereddata.value;
}
```

Hope my code works. Keep coding

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have

```
<input type="text" class="my-input">
<button>click me!</button>
```

you can retrieve input value in jQuery/Javascript with this instruction;

```
$(".my-input").val();
```

if you want to bind the data retrieval to the "click me!" button there is the complete code:

```
$(".click-me").click(function() {
    alert($(".my-input").val());
});
```

Comment: @Beckham i saw your fiddle... the problem is you cannot return a value from a callback function  the way you do... i fixed your fiddle according to my post: https://jsfiddle.net/1t5pxhj5/5/